# Very simple AJAX/Jquery/JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've just started learning how to use JSON, and I'm having trouble with a very simple page-- I'm trying to pass a number to PHP, add it to the database, and retrieving a (somewhat random) array to be displayed in the info div. The text from the text box is successfully entered in the database, however, I'm not getting any return from the JSON encoded array.

```
<?php
    include_once('functions.php');
    if (isset($_GET['number'])){
        $num = $_GET['number'];
        dbQuery("INSERT INTO `wheels` (`wheelNo`) VALUES ($num);");
        $blah = Array();
        $blah['item1'] = 'hats';
        $blah['item2'] = 'shoes';
        echo json_encode($blah);
     }
?>


<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#sub').click(function(){
                var num = $('#num').val();
                $.getJSON('test.php','number='+num, function(data) {    
                    $('#info').html(data.item1);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <button id="sub">Submit</button>
    <input type="text" id="num" />
    <div id="info">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your HTML will be tacked on to the end of your JSON causing it to be invalid, try calling [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) immediately after `json_encode()` to make sure nothing else is printed to the page.

Answer (score 0):

to stop the reading of the code after the `echo json_encode($blah);` try to type `die();` thereafter